# Android Volley - Post Request - Not Sending parameter to php

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I was trying to make a POST request with parameter through Volley. It is working totally fine to response query result from database IN MY ANDROID APP but when i show the values of this query in php the then show error undefined index variable "uploaded_by".

JAVA CODE:

```
 StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
                params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
                params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
                return params;
            }

        };

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
```

---

1. Heading

   ## #

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
//This script is designed by Android-Examples.com
//Define your host here.
$servername = "localhost";
//Define your database username here.
$username = "root";
//Define your database password here.
$password = "";
//Define your database name here.
$dbname = "u288012116_and";

$connection = new mysqli($servername,$username,$password,$dbname) ;

// Innitialize Variable
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 {

 $StudentData = $_POST['uploaded_by'];




          //fetch table rows from mysql db
$sql = "SELECT image_title,image_url FROM  `imagelistviewtable` WHERE  `uploaded_by` = '". $StudentData . "'";


$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " . mysqli_error($connection));

    //create an array
$emparray = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $emparray[] = $row;
    }


$json = json_encode($emparray);
if ($json === false) {
    // Avoid echo of empty string (which is invalid JSON), and
    // JSONify the error message instead:
    $json = json_encode(array("jsonError", json_last_error_msg()));
    if ($json === false) {
        // This should not happen, but we go all the way now:
        $json = '{"jsonError": "unknown"}';
    }
    // Set HTTP response status code to: 500 - Internal Server Error
    http_response_code(500);
}

echo $json;
//close the db connection
    mysqli_close($connection);
 }

    ?>
```

Comment: You don't send a `uploaded_by` `_POST` variable anywhere..you will have to put it in your params

Comment: but i want to execute query in my php file according to user input data in edittext of android app with where clause check my php code i want to receive query information from database and show in php file with json format

Comment: the key of the input edittext is uploaded_by which i declared in constant  KEY_USERNAME

Comment: try using `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
 { print_r($_POST); return; }` and share the results

Comment: same error nothing show in php file mean not receive post request parameter in php from android app but server response fine in android app and also show the information regarding query but php file have error

Comment: php file not receive key parameter from android app

Comment: is the `REGISTER_URL` the correct one? Does a Toast appears? what happens...

Comment: yes i successfully received information from database regarding query in toast message of android app.and REGISTER_URL is local server link where php file have

Comment: I really can't understand what you are saying..re-update your question and make sure to be well - formatted and clean..

Comment: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/ check this tutorial i want to show values in php file but thsi tutorial insert in database simple

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void getServerData(final Context cntx) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(cntx);


        JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                Request.Method.POST, "Url", json_object,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                         // Your response

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }

                }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {

                // Your header parameter if you have otherwise this is optional

                return headers;
            }
        };
   queue.add(jsObjRequest);
}
```

Comment: i want to execute query in my php file according to user input data in edittext of android app with where clause check my php code i want to receive query information from database and show in php file with json format

Comment: the main issue is php variable not receive value from android app so that why it can't execute query in php file and get information from database

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to answer this, but I think it may help someone facing same problem.
I search through all similar questions on SO, relating to PHP and Volley api but I didn't find any satisfying answer.

The problem is that you are sending data from the Volley library as content type

> application/json

but your PHP script is expecting POST data as content type

> application/x-www-form-urlencoded

In your PHP script, do this:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

if ( !empty($_POST['uploaded_by']) ) {

    $StudentData = $_POST['uploaded_by'];
    echo $StudentData;
}
```

Now if you check for

```
if( isset($_POST['uploaded_by']) ){

    echo "something";
}
```

it should work now